# Putting assembly code into Macro creates an unknown token in expression error

Tags: macos, assembly, macros, x86-64, att

So, I created a quine in Assembly. And wanted to put parts of the code into a macro. However as soon as I do that, I get a warning saying:

instantiation :9:6: error: unknown token in expression
 mov , %rcx

Grace.s:28:1: note: while in macro instantiation
notmain(x)

Here is the code in question with the macro (Gets error)

```
.macro nomain
_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    lea name(%rip), %rdi
    lea write(%rip), %rsi
    call _fopen
    mov %rax, %rdi
    mov $10, %rdx
    mov $9, %rcx
    mov $34, %r8
    lea quine(%rip), %r9
    lea quine(%rip), %rsi
    call _fprintf
    leave
    ret
.endmacro

.data
quine: .string ".data%1$cquine: .string %3$c%4$s%3$c%1$cname: .string %3$cGrace_kid.s%3$c%1$cwrite: .string %3$cw%3$c%1$c%1$c.text%1$c.globl _main%1$c#main function%1$c_main:%1$c%2$cpush %%rbp%1$c%2$cmov %%rsp, %%rbp%1$c%2$clea name(%%rip), %%rdi%1$c%2$clea write(%%rip), %%rsi%1$c%2$ccall _fopen%1$c%2$cmov %%rax, %%rdi%1$c%2$cmov $10, %%rdx%1$c%2$cmov $9, %%rcx%1$c%2$cmov $34, %%r8%1$c%2$clea quine(%%rip), %%r9%1$c%2$clea quine(%%rip), %%rsi%1$c%2$ccall _fprintf%1$c%2$cleave%1$c%2$cret%1$c"
name: .string "Grace_kid.s"
write: .string "w"

.text
.globl _main
#main function
nomain
```

and without macro (Works)

```
.data
quine: .string ".data%1$cquine: .string %3$c%4$s%3$c%1$cname: .string %3$cGrace_kid.s%3$c%1$cwrite: .string %3$cw%3$c%1$c%1$c.text%1$c.globl _main%1$c#main function%1$c_main:%1$c%2$cpush %%rbp%1$c%2$cmov %%rsp, %%rbp%1$c%2$clea name(%%rip), %%rdi%1$c%2$clea write(%%rip), %%rsi%1$c%2$ccall _fopen%1$c%2$cmov %%rax, %%rdi%1$c%2$cmov $10, %%rdx%1$c%2$cmov $9, %%rcx%1$c%2$cmov $34, %%r8%1$c%2$clea quine(%%rip), %%r9%1$c%2$clea quine(%%rip), %%rsi%1$c%2$ccall _fprintf%1$c%2$cleave%1$c%2$cret%1$c"
name: .string "Grace_kid.s"
write: .string "w"

.text
.globl _main
#main function
_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    lea name(%rip), %rdi
    lea write(%rip), %rsi
    call _fopen
    mov %rax, %rdi
    mov $10, %rdx
    mov $9, %rcx
    mov $34, %r8
    lea quine(%rip), %r9
    lea quine(%rip), %rsi
    call _fprintf
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Include the code directly into your question, so we know it's a GAS `.macro` as opposed to a CPP `#define` macro (which would also work in a .S file).  SO requires questions to be self-contained.  (You might want to make a [mcve] of just the part of the macro that gives the error, without the full quine.)

Comment: Assembles fine in my version of `gas` (v2.22) after I fix the `.endmacro` to `.endm`.

Comment: @Jester That didn't fix it for me, ill check if I have the same gas version as you

Comment: @PeterCordes Added the full code with and without the macro. It seems the compiler dosen't see the $9 portion of "mov $9, %rcx" when I put it inside the macro.

Comment: Since you seem to be using XCODE and possibly an older clang you may find yourself having to use `$$` instead of `$` inside macros when dealing with immediate values.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! Should have thought of that...

Comment: What would be useful is to post the version of MacOS you are using and what the version shown by `clang -v` shows.